# postgresql 8.4 original config files (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, postgresql

Where can I find the original postgresql 8.4 config files for ubuntu (/etc/postgresql/8.4/main/*)?

Upgraded ubuntu to version 9.10. which included upgrading postgresql from 8.3 to 8.4

dir with config files is empty (/etc/postgresql/8.4/main/)

Completely removed and then reinstalled all ubuntu postgres packages (server, client, admin), but that didn't reinstall/populate the config files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to totally reinstall postgresql I suggest you run

```
dpkg --list | grep postgresql
```

and then run

```
dpkg --purge <insert package here>
```

for each package that the list command returned (most likely postgresql-common and postgresql-8.4

and then reinstall using aptitude install postgresql, this will remove and then bring all the config files back.

Comment: adam: thanks, this worked. The --purge must have done it since I had not used that option before.